# update the database while using the timer

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I'm working on my python script to write the data in a sqlite3 database at the same time when using the time.sleep function. I'm having a trouble with writing the database at the same time when I'm using the time.sleep function.

I can be able to create the database table without have any problem, but when I use the time.sleep function, it will stop writing the data into the database.

When I use this code:

```
import time
import threading

#DOWNLOAD THE XML SOURCE HERE
url = ADDON.getSetting('allchannel.url')
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
response.close()
profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide',''))
self.getControl(4202).setLabel("1%")


if os.path.exists(profilePath):
   profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
   con = database.connect(profilePath)
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(channel TEXT, title TEXT, start_date TIMESTAMP, stop_date TIMESTAMP, description TEXT)')
   con.commit()
   con.close
   tv_elem = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(data)).getroot()
   profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))
   profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
   con = sqlite3.connect(profilePath)
   cur = con.cursor()
   channels = OrderedDict()

   # Get the loaded data
   for channel in tv_elem.findall('channel'):
       channel_name = channel.find('display-name').text
       for program in channel.findall('programme'):
           title = program.find('title').text
           start_time = program.get("start")
           stop_time = program.get("stop")
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time])
           con.commit()
           con.close

           time.sleep(2)
           #Stop the timer and set the timer again for 2 seconds
           self.getControl(4202).setLabel("8%")

           time.sleep(2)
           #Stop the timer and set the timer again for another 2 seconds
           self.getControl(4202).setLabel("16%")

           time.sleep(2)
           #Stop the timer and set the timer again for another 2 seconds
           self.getControl(4202).setLabel("24%")
```

So when I try this without using the time.sleep function:

```
   # Get the loaded data
   for channel in tv_elem.findall('channel'):
       channel_name = channel.find('display-name').text
       for program in channel.findall('programme'):
           title = program.find('title').text
           start_time = program.get("start")
           stop_time = program.get("stop")
           cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time])
           con.commit()
           con.close
```

It will allow me to write the data into the database if I use without the time.sleep function. I want to use the time.sleep function or the timer, because I want to update the string in the setLabel function in every 2 seconds while I'm writing the data into the database. I tried to use the while loop, it will freeze the application that I'm running on.

Can you please tell me how I can write the data into the database at the same time when I'm using the time.sleep or the timer function?

Edit: I get too many prints when I running the threading:

```
15:39:51 T:6980  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:2104  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6924  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6052  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1696  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6164  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1312  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:3804  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6364  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:4208  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:3332  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5428  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:920  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6408  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:7000  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1988  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5544  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6620  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6448  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1536  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1132  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6548  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1892  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6532  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:3856  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:788  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6416  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5692  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5256  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6696  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1352  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6656  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:4844  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:4672  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:3636  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:7052  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6264  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6336  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6332  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:7064  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:7148  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6984  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:4924  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5716  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6960  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:1828  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5492  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6560  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:3328  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6880  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6152  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6892  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:5048  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6788  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6168  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:4656  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6392  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:51 T:6928  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6824  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6716  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5384  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6008  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:2280  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:2612  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6012  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6820  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7080  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:2556  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:3904  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4284  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5648  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6076  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6516  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6552  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6768  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:3464  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:1240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:1992  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6896  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6288  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6212  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6672  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7040  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6280  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7112  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5760  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6664  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6952  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7024  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6224  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5356  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5628  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4220  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6160  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6320  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4384  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6572  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5284  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7060  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:3256  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5008  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6124  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:912  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5408  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5560  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4052  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4416  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5392  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6236  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:5940  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:540  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:4596  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:3796  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6700  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6772  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:7092  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:52 T:6868  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5292  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6440  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6060  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5360  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5984  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6900  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4412  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:2812  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5756  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4048  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5596  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6936  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6612  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:1768  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5496  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3168  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4444  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:7036  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:2896  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:7164  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6032  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6912  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4448  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3132  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6708  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6556  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6184  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6588  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5700  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6404  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6244  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3528  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:7132  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6808  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6004  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:876  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5080  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6668  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5580  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5488  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6344  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5732  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4160  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6300  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3472  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:2772  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3444  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6568  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6856  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:984  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6748  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6920  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5712  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6248  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5532  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5344  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:1484  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:5804  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:3632  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6780  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:4760  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:6888  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:53 T:7156  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6932  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7144  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6980  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4128  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6956  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6924  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6376  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5820  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6052  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1696  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1312  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3804  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4208  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5428  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6408  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6728  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5544  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6448  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1132  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1892  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3856  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6416  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5256  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5536  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2860  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4844  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4268  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3636  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7052  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6264  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6508  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2728  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3608  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5764  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7064  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7148  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3616  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5716  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:416  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6216  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1828  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5492  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6560  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4392  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7096  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6436  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5048  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6788  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3300  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6392  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5608  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4976  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5752  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2944  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4640  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2268  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6716  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2148  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5500  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5416  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5384  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5512  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5844  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2280  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:2612  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6012  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6820  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3904  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5648  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6516  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6768  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:3464  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6896  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7040  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6672  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5760  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6664  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:7024  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5956  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6632  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5452  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5356  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6704  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6352  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6660  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:1436  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6252  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6348  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6832  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:5628  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:4220  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:54 T:6160  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7004  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6740  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6572  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6592  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7116  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6504  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5008  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6636  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1172  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4156  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5560  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6188  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6120  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6576  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6324  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6712  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5940  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6064  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7008  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4596  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6700  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7092  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5292  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6060  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5360  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4412  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:2812  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6724  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4048  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:2104  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5596  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5196  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:2892  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4484  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6164  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6608  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6364  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4444  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7036  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:2896  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6620  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6548  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:788  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6696  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6656  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4672  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5224  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1500  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6332  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5260  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4924  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6964  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6960  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6880  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6304  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6168  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6928  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6600  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7164  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6872  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6824  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4616  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6708  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6556  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:3224  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1032  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1492  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6008  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6904  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:3440  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:3528  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6004  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6232  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6808  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6668  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:5732  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4160  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6300  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:2772  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:3444  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6568  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1240  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:1992  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6212  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6920  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6248  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6280  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:7112  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6952  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:6224  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:55 T:4172  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6780  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:4760  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6888  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6308  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6752  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6764  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:1856  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:5464  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6784  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:4384  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:5232  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:4128  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:5284  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6376  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:3256  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:1312  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:3804  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:6408  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:5392  NOTICE: hello, world
15:39:56 T:1132  NOTICE: hello, world
```

Comment: Do you use the sleep function just to make a progress bar to your app?

Comment: @OrDuan No I don't make the progress bar in my application, I'm only using the sleep function to processing how far I'm writing the data into the database. Hope this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with with the way you choose to do the progressbar, basicly sleep the app sounds bad idea to me, and you might want to find a better way to do it.

But, if you want to run 2 different actions - you need to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). A small example

```
def function_1():
    for i in range(5):
        print "1111"
        time.sleep(1)

def function_2():
    for i in range(5):
        print "2222"
        time.sleep(1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=function_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=function_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

If you were called the 2 functions without threading you would get and out of all the '111's and then all the '222's.

When using threading i got this:

```
1111
2222
2222
1111
1111
2222
2222
1111
2222
1111
```

Because it happened paralleled.
Hope it was clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I'm having a problem with creating the thread, it will not let me to print the "8%" and "16". Do you know why?

Comment: it's okay now I can be able to read the threading to print it, but i get too many same prints of "hello world" when I want to print it only once using the code `self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.hello) self.thread.setDaemon(True) self.thread.start()`. Do you know how I can print the `hello world` only once? Please see at my update code.

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` is a blocking function hence it stops the processing - you need to either move your database writes to a separate thread, see the manual on threading or subprocess, or you need to update your string from a timer, also in the manual.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, can you please show me an example code that I need to move my database writes to a separate thread?

Comment: Since you are only updating the string in the box why not use a timer for that?

Comment: I have tried to use the timer but the database will not be written unless I have to move the setLabel function to seperate thread. If you know a way i would be very grateful.

Comment: Get rid of the sleep and use a timer handler that updates calls the setLabel function.  If your GUI library has no call after function then have the timer set a flag and in your `for program` loop check the flag and if it is set update the label and clear the flag.